# How to prove the given statement based on the conditions related to interpolating polynomials used in Adaptive Backward Differentiation Formula.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, interpolation, numerical-calculus, lagrange-interpolation

Full disclosure: This was part of my homework that I couldn't solve completely. Also, I wasn't sure how to give a proper title to this question.

Before going to the statement to prove, I think some context is necessary, and hopefully through my explanation you would also get an idea on the gaps in my understanding of the problem.

---

**The context:**
To numerically solve an ODE given by $y'=f(x,y),\;\;y(x_0)=y_0$
The BDF method is constructed using the interpolating polynomial $p$ of degree $k$ from the following $k+1$ (not equidistant) data points:
$$(x_{i-k+1},y_{i-k+1}),...,(x_i,y_i),(x_i+1,y_i+1)$$
with the unknown value $y_{k+1}$. The unknown value is determined by the demand $(A)$:
$$p'(x_{i+1})=f(x_{i+1},p(x_{i+1}))$$

For adaptive step-size, we introduce another polynomial $q$ of degree $k$ from the following $k+1$ (not equidistant) data points:
$$(x_{i-k},y_{i-k}),(x_{i-k},y_{i-k}),\dots,(x_i,y_i)$$

The polynomials are constructed using Newton's Interpolation.

---

**The problem:**
Prove the following: The two conditions, $(A)$ and $p(x_{i+1}) = y_{i+1}$ imply:
$$0 = q'(x_{i+1}) + \alpha_{i+1}(y_{i+1} - q(x_{i+1})) - f(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$$

where,
$$\alpha_{i+1} = \dfrac{1}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}} + \dfrac{1}{x_{i+1}-x_{i-1}} + \dots + \dfrac{1}{x_{i+1}-x_{i-k+1}} $$

---

**My attempt:**
I recognized how the two conditions can be substituted into the statement:
$$
0 = q'(x_{i+1}) + \alpha_{i+1}(y_{i+1} - q(x_{i+1})) - f(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})\\ 
0 = q'(x_{i+1}) + \alpha_{i+1}(p(x_{i+1}) - q(x_{i+1})) - p'(x_{i+1}) \\
p'(x_{i+1}) -  q'(x_{i+1}) = \alpha_{i+1}(p(x_{i+1}) - q(x_{i+1}))\\ 
$$
finally forming:
$$ \alpha_{i+1} = \dfrac{p'(x_{i+1}) -  q'(x_{i+1})}{(p(x_{i+1}) - q(x_{i+1}))} $$

In the next step I can construct the two polynomials $p$ and $q$ and subtract them to hopefully get the expression for $\alpha$.

Through Newton's Interpolation method, I constructed $q$ to be:
$$q(x) = [y_{i-k}] + [y_{i-k},y_{i-k+1}](x-x_{i-k}) + [y_{i-k},y_{i-k+1},y_{i-k+2}](x-x_{i-k})(x-x_{i-k+1}) + ... + [y_{i-k},...,y_{i}](x-x_{i-k})\dots(x-x_{i-1})$$
where $[y_0,y_1,...y_k]$ are determined by [divided difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences)

$p(x)$ is constructed similarly by just adding 1 in the subscripts to match its corresponding data points.

$$p(x) = [y_{i-k+1}] + [y_{i-k+1},y_{i-k+2}](x-x_{i-k+1}) + ... + [y_{i-k+1},...,y_{i+1}](x-x_{i-k+1})\dots(x-x_{i})$$

Now I am unsure how to proceed from here, since the subtraction of $p$ and $q$ doesn't seem to be the right idea. Also, I have to take derivative of the polynomials as well? I think there might be an easier way.

Your  help would be appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpolation polynomial over all data points from $i-k$ to $i+1$ can be written in Newton form in different ways, depending on the order of the points. So you get by introducing $x_{n-k}$ last on the left side and $x_{i+1}$ last on the right side
$$
p(x)+y[x_{i-k},...,x_{i+1}](x-x_{n-k+1})...(x-x_i)(x-x_{i+1})
\\=q(x)+y[x_{i-k},...,x_{i+1}](x-x_{n-k})(x-x_{n-k+1})...(x-x_{i})
$$
or
$$
p(x)-q(x)=y[x_{i-k},...,x_{i+1}](x-x_{n-k+1})...(x-x_{i})\cdot(x_{i+1}-x_{n-k}).
$$

Now take the logarithmic derivative
$$
\frac{p'(x)-q'(x)}{p(x)-q(x)}=\frac1{x-x_{n-k+1}}+...+\frac1{x-x_i}
$$
as constant factors reduce to zero under the logarithmic derivative.

Finally, evaluating at $x=x_{i+1}$ gives the claim.

Comment: Logarithmic derivative?! That didn't even cross my mind. What made you think of using it?

Comment: The form of $\alpha$. I was writing the theoretical part of the article on Newton identities in wikipedia, as I was using the same in some algebra work. The same logarithmic derivative appears in some analysis of Newton's method and its extension to the Durand-Kerner and Aberth-Ehrlich methods. Generally it is useful for the derivative of products with more than 2 factors.